# Pandas DataFrame - Best way to transform multiple input columns to multiple output columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple function that takes a sequence of numbers, and returns a tuple of 4 values, eg the (min, max, first, last) elements of the sequence. *(This is just an example; I can't just use builtins to get each value; I need to actually use my function).* I'd like to apply this function to all columns of a DataFrame and return the results in a new DataFrame, preserving the index.

A couple days ago I did the following: Convert the initial DataFrame into a Series of input tuples; `apply()` my function to create a Series of output tuples; and create a new DataFrame from this output Series, expanding the output tuples into individual columns. And it works fine ...

```
def fn(a): return (min(a), max(a), a[0], a[-1])

df = pd.DataFrame([(2, 4, 5, 1, 3), (12, 14, 15, 11, 13), (20, 40, 50, 10, 30)], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
sr = pd.Series(df.to_numpy().tolist(), index=df.index)
sr2 = sr.apply(fn)
print(pd.DataFrame(sr2.values.tolist(), index=df.index))

    0   1   2   3
a   1   5   2   3
b  11  15  12  13
c  10  50  20  30
```

However, now that a couple of days have passed and the thrill of victory has faded, it feels like this code can't be right, it's too many steps, it's insufficiently vectorized, and I'm sure I'm missing something.

Is there a simpler/faster/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
def first(x): return x.iloc[0]
def last(x): return x.iloc[-1]

out = df.agg(['min', 'max', first, last], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   min  max  first  last
a    1    5      2     3
b   11   15     12    13
c   10   50     20    30
```

##### alternative

```
def fn(a): return (np.min(a, 1), np.max(a, 1), a.iloc[:,0], a.iloc[:,-1])

pd.concat(fn(df), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question to make it more clear that my trival 'min max etc' function was just an example, and the real function cannot just be replaced by a series of builtins.

If I followed the method in your answer, I would be ditching my function, and instead I'd write 4 functions, one for each value, and then calling `agg()` with all 4 functions. I'd prefer to avoid this if possible -- among other things it'd mean digging into the function and recreating the logic for each value.

Comment: Upvoting since it's a nice illustration of using multiple arguments tp `agg()`, which I would not have thought of, even though it's not quite what I'm looking for as an answer.

Comment: The issue is that your function is not vectorized, you should update it to handle the whole DataFrame. I added an example

Comment: This appears to be the same idea ... scrapping the (potentially very complicated) function that returns 4 values, in favor of 4 individual functions, each of which returns one of the 4 values from the original function. Also, it looks like it requires each of those 4 smaller functions to numpy builtins or the like. I do appreciate the comment though.

Comment: You should provide a minimal example of your function, showing how your functions are interdependent. As it is now, it really looks like you cannot vectorize your operations.

Comment: After learning a bit more about how vectorization actually works, I agree. Accepted.